# multiple divs responsive with css

Tags: css, html

I have searched high and low for days and trying to get two divs side by side (50% wide each) and a second div below at 100% wide...also the two top divs need to change with responsive vieing. i.e right div falls under the left div when screen size is at say 960px wide.

I have tried this code, but the right div displays smaller when you start to reduce the browser size.

I'm sure I have this all wrong, but it's a learning stage for me, so sorry for a basic question! Any help would be so great!!!

Sorry...I can post an image to explain, but to help clear it up, I need in one row, two divs side by side (50% wide each) and in row 2, 1 div that takes up 100% width.

OK! I can add an image now of what I need to achieve! Images 1, 2, 3 will be different sizes along with the amount of text below the image. The layout (example) image is not to scale, and on the site will need a clear background (no colour) The background colours are just to show different the divs in the example.

[image: Sample layout]

And this is how it should look in responsive...

[image: Responsive example]

HTML:

```
<div class="custom_div">
<div id="one">one</div>
<div id="two">two</div>
<div id="three">three</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.custom_div {
overflow:hidden;
}
.custom_div div {
min-height: 100%;
padding: 10px;
text-align: center;
}
#one {
background-color: gray;
float:left;
margin-right:0px;
width:50%;
}
#two {
background-color: white;
overflow:hidden;
margin-right: 20px;
margin: 1px;
width:auto;
min-height: 50%;
}
#three {
background-color: yellow;
margin-right:auto;
margin-left:auto;
width: 100%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
#one {
    float: none;
    margin-right:0;
    width:auto;
}
}
```

Comment: everything seems to work fine : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/5RGaf/

Comment: What is the wrong with this question i didnt understand ? Everything is fine

Comment: @user3580520 - I've updated my answer below (http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/UkhAR/39/) - the problem with the accepted answer and my original one was that you risk layout breakages when content of varying sizing is added to the first two div elements. This revised solution not only prevents that but implements correct scaling (you cant achieve with floats alone)

Comment: @SW4 Your fiddle shows 3 divs in one single column, not the two top divs split?

Comment: @user3580520 - increase the size of the window and the top two will split

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below code:

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/UkhAR/33/)

```
html, body{height:100%;}
.custom_div{width:100%;}
.custom_div div {
     background:#ccc;
     box-sizing:border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
 }
 #one, #two {
     width:50%;
     float:left;
     height:100%;
 }
 .clearfix{clear:both; display:block;}
 @media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
    #one, #two {
      width:auto;
      float:none;
    }
 }
```

Comment: I don't know what it is but your code, but it worked a treat...thank you so much! I can't +1 you!

Comment: This displays great in Firefox, but in ie and chrome, all divs align in a single vertical column

Comment: This Code will break when one of the first two column has more data then other : See the Fiddle : jsfiddle.net/UkhAR/32

Comment: @PradeepPansari - your CSS above does not match the fiddle

Comment: @Pradeep Pansari - How can we add padding to the divs an cotraol how the padding acts in responsive mode? Sorry for a dumb question, but I'm learning!

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE:**

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/UkhAR/39/)

The only foolproof way to do this to ensure correct sizing on differing levels of content:

HTML

```
<div class='table'>
    <div class='cell'></div>
    <div class='cell'></div>
    <div class='caption'></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.table {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}
.cell {
    display:table-cell;
}
.caption {
    display:table-caption;
    caption-side:bottom;
}
.cell, .caption {
    height:20px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
    .table .cell, .caption {
        display:block;
    }
}
```

---

**Original Answer**

How about the below?

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UkhAR/3/)

HTML

```
<div class="left">left</div>
<div class="right">right</div>
<div class="full">content</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    border:1px solid black;
    box-sizing:border-box;.
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
}
.left, .right {
    width:50%;
}
.left {
    float:left;
}
.right {
    float:right;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .left, .right {
        width:auto;
        float:none;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the down-vote on this? This is how I interpreted the question also.

Comment: this looks fine to me

Comment: No idea what the downvoting is about here unless I have totally missed the point of the question- which, given it has been clearly expressed..is unlikely.

Comment: +1 This looks the most relevant answer on direct interpretation of question.

Comment: I thank everyone for their input, and for the a speedy reply. I give a +1 to everyone who added their code ideas! As a learner, these inputs are so important for us newbies to learn from, and it's great to see different ways to achieve the same results.
Thankyou all!

Comment: This Code will break when one of the first two column has more data then other : 
See the Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/UkhAR/32/

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the Updated Fiddle : **http://jsfiddle.net/PEvLt/3/**

I've removed unnecessary properties.
The problem was with the padding and margins.
The thing you should add is always use BOX-SIZING Property.
It'll help you when you are using padding with the widths/heights defined in %

More about Box-Sizing.
http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

**UPDATE** : You need to wrap the first column into one single div or need to clear floats after first 2 columns to avoid overlapping of the third column.

HTML :

```
<div class="first_two">
    <div id="one">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/200/" width="100%"/>
    </div>
    <div id="two">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/" width="100%"/>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div id="three">three</div>
```

CSS :

```
    *{
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         
}
.first_two {
    background:#3498db;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#one {
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
}
#two {
    width:50%;
    float:left;
    height:100%;
}
#three {
    background-color:#8e44ad;
    width: 100%;
}
.clear{
    clear:both;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    #one,#two {
       width:100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code almost worked, but the full width div would not display the image on the front end of the site...Thank you heaps for your input, and I'm interested that your code also included browser references and no one else did? Wll read more into yur CSS link you provided.

Comment: @user3580520 : Welcome. I didn't get what you've said about image !

Comment: I retested and Firefox has an issue with not displaying the image in the full width div, but ie and chrome works great?

Comment: @user3580520 : I've updated code for better stability and also added images to check if it is working or not. Check the latest fiddle in answer.

Answer (score -2):

you can set the width of **body** tag using javascript

```
<script>
  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.width=screen.width+"px";
</script>
```